# Transmiting analog signal with lora

Tags: audio, adc, modulation, transmitter, lora

I want to transmit an analog signal over *Frequency Modulation* with a *Lora RA 02* module. First thing I need to do is convert the analog signal from the audio source to digital, right?. But I had so problems with it since Lora use *Chrip Spread Spectrum (CSS)*. I can't hear my audio signal using my old FM radio receiver which works in frequency modulations. So, can I do something with it?

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible? You might as well ask how to use the LoRa Ra-02 as a linear power supply.

Comment: I think there is something i can do with it, like changing the modulation technique, flashing a modified firmware or something.

Comment: If you want to receive with an FM receiver, you have to transmit with FM, not with LoRa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LoRa RA 02 module](https://www.elecrow.com/sx1278-lora-module-433m-10km-ra-02-wireless-spread-spectrum-transmission-socket-for-smart-home-diy.html) possibly uses 433 MHz as the main carrier frequency.

> *I can't hear my audio signal using my old FM radio receiver which is
> works in frequency modulations.*

Your old radio receiver will be able to tune between 88 MHz and 108 MHz so, it's extremely unlikely that you will be able to pick-up LoRa transmissions.

> *So, can i do something with it?*

Probably not because, apart from the vast difference in carrier frequency, the audio signal is digitized and transmitted whereas for an analogue broadcast radio set-up, the carrier is frequency modulated with an analogue audio signal.

Comment: I don’t think LoRa has the data rate to send audio. It is meant to be low power, low data rate digital.

Comment: @Kartman maybe you should post this more directly to the OP or leave it as a new answer? You could probably send reasonable MP3 encoded audio through it.